# Terraform Multi-Region Deployment using Modules

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

terraform modules which planed to deploy aws resources in single region. then I changed code assign values based on condtional varible "var.site" to deploy in another region as well.

provider.tf as below

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "xxxxxx"
  region  = "ap-southeast-1"
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      site        = "PRIM"
    }
  }
}

# Provider configurations for secondary region
provider "aws" {
  profile = "xxxxx"
  region  = "us-east-1"
  alias   = "secondary_site"
  default_tags {
    tags = {
      site        = "SECO"
    }
  }
}
```

I just want to create vpc, security groups and backup vault in another region then
copy primary region backup to secondary region.
my primary region alreay privision using terraform.
When I used count parameter as below

```
module "addc" {
  source = "./modules/ec2/addc"

  project                                                = var.project
  environment                                            = var.environmen
  addc_instance_profile_name                             = module.iam.addc_instance_profile_name
  count                                                  = var.site == "SECO" ? 0 : 1
}

module "route53" {
  source = "./modules/route53"

  site                            = var.site
  internal_domain                 = var.internal_domain
  dns_server_ips                  = var.dns_server_ips
  vpc_id                          = module.networking.vpc_id
  private_subnets_ids             = module.networking.private_subnets_ids
  public_subnets_ids              = module.networking.public_subnets_ids
  addc_network_interface_id       = module.addc[0].addc_network_interface_id
}
```

configuraton match with primary site without count varible. then I added count paramter .Then I executed this code using primary region provider (var.site=="PRIM") I expect to code shoud be equivalent current state file. But it trying re-create adddc instance in primary region. how to use same module to  create  resources in secondary region based on var.site varible.seems count paramter change the current state file and force to destroy and  re-create exsiting resources

I have tried  to use count parameter. But then It trying  destroy exsisting resources and re-create my exsiting ec2.
expected:

```
No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration
```

result :

```
Plan: 4 to add, 4 to change, 4 to destroy.
```

Comment: Where is the `provider.tf` configured?

Comment: Here's the documentation you should read https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/modules/develop/providers

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to add `count` to a `module` block which already has real infrastructure associated with it, without Terraform proposing to destroy the existing infrastructure and create new objects at a different address.

Terraform can only see the *current* configuration and it cannot see how you've changed the configuration since the last run or guess what you meant by changing the configuration in this way. By default Terraform assumes that if a particular object is no longer mentioned in the configuration then you intend to destroy it.

For situations where that's not what you intended, you can give Terraform extra information about how you changed your configuration by writing a `moved` block alongside the `module` block:

```
module "addc" {
  source = "./modules/ec2/addc"
  count  = var.site == "SECO" ? 0 : 1

  # ...
}

moved {
  from = module.addc
  to   = module.addc[0]
}
```

This extra `moved` block tells Terraform that if there are objects in the state associated with `module.addc` and there are *not* yet objects in the state associated with `module.addc[0]` then when planning Terraform should pretend that the existing objects had originally been created within `module.addc[0]`. As long as all of the individual `resource` blocks are unchanged within the module, this should allow Terraform to see that no changes are needed for any of those objects.

The other possibility is that `var.site == "SECO"` and therefore `module.addc[0]` does not exist at all. In that case, Terraform will first interpret all of the existing objects to belong to `module.addc[0]` but then notice that `module.addc[0]` does not exist in the configuration, and so it will propose to destroy all of those objects. You should therefore make sure that `var.site != "SECO"` in all configurations where you wish to retain the existing objects Terraform is managing.